# Is this a bug in gcc optimizer?

Tags: c++, c++14

When I compile following code with `gcc 6 -O3 -std=c++14`, I get nice and empty `main`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x00000000004003e0 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000004003e2 <+2>:     retq
```

But uncommenting last line in main "breaks" optimization:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x00000000004005f0 <+0>:     sub    $0x78,%rsp
   0x00000000004005f4 <+4>:     lea    0x40(%rsp),%rdi
   0x00000000004005f9 <+9>:     movq   $0x400838,0x10(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400602 <+18>:    movb   $0x0,0x18(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400607 <+23>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000400610 <+32>:    mov    %rax,0x68(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400615 <+37>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400617 <+39>:    movl   $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x000000000040061e <+46>:    movq   $0x400838,0x30(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400627 <+55>:    movb   $0x0,0x38(%rsp)
   0x000000000040062c <+60>:    movl   $0x0,0x20(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400634 <+68>:    movq   $0x400838,0x50(%rsp)
   0x000000000040063d <+77>:    movb   $0x0,0x58(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400642 <+82>:    movl   $0x0,0x40(%rsp)
   0x000000000040064a <+90>:    callq  0x400790 <ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()>
   0x000000000040064f <+95>:    lea    0x20(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000400654 <+100>:   callq  0x400790 <ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()>
   0x0000000000400659 <+105>:   mov    %rsp,%rdi
   0x000000000040065c <+108>:   callq  0x400790 <ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()>
   0x0000000000400661 <+113>:   mov    0x68(%rsp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400666 <+118>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
   0x000000000040066f <+127>:   jne    0x400678 <main()+136>
   0x0000000000400671 <+129>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400673 <+131>:   add    $0x78,%rsp
   0x0000000000400677 <+135>:   retq   
   0x0000000000400678 <+136>:   callq  0x4005c0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

Code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>

namespace
{
struct ErasedTypeVTable
{
   using destructor_t = void (*)(void *obj);

   destructor_t dtor;
};

template <typename T>
void dtor(void *obj)
{
   return static_cast<T *>(obj)->~T();
}

template <typename T>
static const ErasedTypeVTable erasedTypeVTable = {
   &dtor<T>
};
}

struct ErasedObject
{
   std::aligned_storage<sizeof(void *)>::type storage;
   const ErasedTypeVTable& vtbl;
   bool flag = false;

   template <typename T, typename S = typename std::decay<T>::type>
   ErasedObject(T&& obj)
   : vtbl(erasedTypeVTable<S>)
   {
      static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(storage) && alignof(T) <= alignof(decltype(storage)), "");
      new (object()) S(std::forward<T>(obj));
   }

   ErasedObject(ErasedObject&& other) = default;

   ~ErasedObject()
   {
      if (flag)
      {
         ::operator delete(object());
      }
      else
      {
         vtbl.dtor(object());
      }
   }

   void *object()
   {
      return reinterpret_cast<char *>(&storage);
   }
};

struct myType
{
   int a;
};

int main()
{
   ErasedObject c1(myType{});
   ErasedObject c2(myType{});
   //ErasedObject c3(myType{});
}
```

clang can optimize-out both versions.

Any ideas what's going on? Am I hitting some optimization limit? If so, is it configurable?

Comment: Look like a bug to me.

Comment: Reproducible in GCC (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug unless it generates incorrect code or less optimized code than generated by a lower optimization level.

Comment: GCC doesn't inline `main()` as aggressively. Try calling it `meow` instead.

Comment: @T.C. you were right. If i put this into another function it is properly optimized. Do you know what's the GCC's reason behind not optimizing `main()` so aggresively?

Comment: @MaciejCencora Perhaps because `main` is not supposed to be hot, and instruction caching is harmed by inlining and unrolling.

Comment: And I thought I knew  a bit of C++... I can't see the point of half of this code :/

Answer (score 5):

I ran `g++` with `-fdump-ipa-inline` to get more information about why functions are or are not inlined.

For the testcase with main() function and three objects created I got:

```
  (...)
  150 Deciding on inlining of small functions.  Starting with size 35.
  151 Enqueueing calls in void {anonymous}::dtor(void*) [with T = myType]/40.
  152 Enqueueing calls in int main()/35.
  153   not inlinable: int main()/35 -> ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()/33, call is unlikely and code size would grow
  154   not inlinable: int main()/35 -> ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()/33, call is unlikely and code size would grow
  155   not inlinable: int main()/35 -> ErasedObject::~ErasedObject()/33, call is unlikely and code size would grow
  (...)
```

This error code is set in gcc/gcc/ipa-inline.c:

```
  else if (!e->maybe_hot_p ()
       && (growth >= MAX_INLINE_INSNS_SINGLE
       || growth_likely_positive (callee, growth)))
{
      e->inline_failed = CIF_UNLIKELY_CALL;
      want_inline = false;
}
```

Then I discovered, that the smallest change to make g++ inline these functions is to add a declaration:

```
int main() __attribute__((hot));
```

I wasn't able to find in code why `int main()` isn't considered hot, but probably this should be left for another question.

More interesting is the the second part of the conditional I pasted above. The intent was to not inline when the code will grow and you produced an example when the code shrinks after complete inlining.

I think this deserves to be reported on [GCC's bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/), but I'm not sure if you can call it a bug - estimation of inline impact is a heuristic and as such it is expected to work correctly in most cases, not all of them.

Comment: I think it's an interesting experiment to run a [creduce](https://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/) to get a minimal example that fails to inline.

Comment: I'd guess that `main()` isn't considered hot because it's undefined behavior for it to be called explicitly or through a pointer (C++11 3.6.1/3: "The function main shall not be used within a program").  So gcc 'knows' that `main()` can only be called once.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are completely right about the undefined behaviour, but as I couldn't find what makes `main()` cold in the GCC source it's still "don't know" for me :) I saw no special cases inside `maybe_hot_p`, so it probably comes from the hot/cold heuristic itself.